# How to set the library in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio, navigation-drawer

I am trying to show about page library in a fragment(Navigation drawer).I am success fully able to set it for the main activity now I am trying to set it in the Navigation Drawer here is my fragment code

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);
    Element versionElement = new Element();
    versionElement.setTitle("Version 6.2");

    Element adsElement = new Element();
    adsElement.setTitle("Advertise with us");

    View aboutPage = new AboutPage(Navigation.this)
            .isRTL(false)
            .addItem(versionElement)
            .addItem(adsElement)
            .addGroup("Connect with us")
            .addEmail("elmehdi.sakout@gmail.com")
            .addFacebook("the.medy")
            .addTwitter("medyo80")
            .addYoutube("UCdPQtdWIsg7_pi4mrRu46vA")
            .addPlayStore("com.ideashower.readitlater.pro")
            .addInstagram("medyo80")
            .addGitHub("medyo")
            .create();

    setContentView(aboutPage);
}
```

the support library that I have used [How to set the about page library in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36858343/how-to-set-the-about-page-library-in-android-studio/36861529?noredirect=1#comment61294384_36861529)

Comment: what is the problem you are facing ?

Comment: it is showing error in View aboutPage = new AboutPage(Navigation.this)

Comment: and setContentView(aboutPage);

Comment: not compiled but when I just pasted it from my main activity to the fragment it show the error in red line

Comment: Umm... Everything after `return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);` is unreachable code

Comment: And setContentView isn't a method in a Fragment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the library constructor take a **context** parameter, and you're doing it the wrong way. just replace  this line:

```
View aboutPage = new AboutPage(Navigation.this)
```

with this:

```
View aboutPage = new AboutPage(getActivity())
```

**Edit:**
at the end of the day you can't call setContentView from fragment, other solutions is to return aboutPage view as this [thraed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18672072/how-to-programmatically-create-the-layout-for-a-fragment) suggest, or as @cricket_007 mentioned to use FragmentManager to add the fragment to specific Activity.

to set the set ContentView [how to set setContentView in fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870159/how-to-set-setcontentview-in-fragment/36870216?noredirect=1#comment61308405_36870216)

Comment: I will try the code in android studio and I will inform  you with any progress @NeelaySrivastava

Comment: The Fragment should be added to the Activity  through a FragmentManager. Calling setContentView is not how to use Fragments

Comment: you're right @cricket_007, and I think the FragmentManager is better solution. I will use that library soon, so I will keep my answer updated with any useful code.

Comment: @mohamed Ibrahim did u find the solution

Comment: I would have explain that way you find in the edit you added by the way, but happy for you :) @NeelaySrivastava