# how to set setContentView in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, setcontentview

I am trying to call a library in a fragment  but dont know how to set it in a fragment I have done it in the main activity but I am getting an error in setting the setContentView in my fragment 
the compile dependency

```
compile 'com.github.medyo:android-about-page:1.0.2'
```

my fragment content view

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View rootView  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation, container, false);
    Element versionElement = new Element();
    versionElement.setTitle("Version 6.2");

    Element adsElement = new Element();
    adsElement.setTitle("Advertise with us");

    View aboutPage = new AboutPage(getActivity())
            .isRTL(false)
            .addItem(versionElement)
            .addItem(adsElement)
            .addGroup("Connect with us")
            .addEmail("elmehdi.sakout@gmail.com")
            .addFacebook("the.medy")
            .addTwitter("medyo80")
            .addYoutube("UCdPQtdWIsg7_pi4mrRu46vA")
            .addPlayStore("com.ideashower.readitlater.pro")
            .addInstagram("medyo80")
            .addGitHub("medyo")
            .create();

    setContentView(aboutPage);
    return rootView;
}
```

I am getting error in the second last line how to solve this.
The following library will work in api 20+
library https://github.com/medyo/android-about-page

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On a fragment you don't call `setContentView` explicitly, you return the view after inflating it, as you are. So instead of calling `setContentView` consider adding the view `aboutPage` to `rootView` or one of its children views.

For example, say your layout `R.layout.fragment_navigation` contains a `LinearLayout` (or any other `ViewGroup` for that matter) with an ID of `content`. You would do this, before your return statement:

```
LinearLayout content = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.content);
content.addView(aboutPage); //<-- Instead of setContentView(aboutPage)
```

You'll have to adjust this to your layout, I don't know what's inside it.

### Full example

[image]

#### fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">
</RelativeLayout>
```

#### CustomFragment.java

```
public class FragmentExample extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
        Element versionElement = new Element();
        versionElement.setTitle("Version 6.2");

        Element adsElement = new Element();
        adsElement.setTitle("Advertise with us");

        View aboutPage = new AboutPage(getActivity())
                .isRTL(false)
                .addItem(versionElement)
                .addItem(adsElement)
                .addGroup("Connect with us")
                .addEmail("elmehdi.sakout@gmail.com")
                .addFacebook("the.medy")
                .addTwitter("medyo80")
                .addYoutube("UCdPQtdWIsg7_pi4mrRu46vA")
                .addPlayStore("com.ideashower.readitlater.pro")
                .addInstagram("medyo80")
                .addGitHub("medyo")
                .create();

        viewGroup.addView(aboutPage);
        return viewGroup;
    }
}
```

Comment: but it is given in the library (I am new in android) so plz guide me

Comment: on adding with the root view or child view it is still giving error

Comment: tried this way  aboutPage.addView(aboutPage); or rootView

Comment: don't add it to itself!

Comment: THE example you are folowing show how to do in a activity.
In a fragment, the method onCreateView must inflate and return the view you want to show.

Answer (score 1):

setContentView() is for Activities, for Fragments you have to return the inflated layout on the onCreateView() method like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
}
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

in Android X you simply can first  import

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
```

and then in constructor pass your layout id like R.layout.fragment_navigation and then just override onViewCreated methode (it,s safer too)and than you just implement onCreateView().
Example:

```
import android.view.View
import android.widget.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment

class MahrInCoinFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_navigation) {

private lateinit var mCoin: Coin

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    // Load coin saved data or use default value
    val cost: Int = Hawk.get(Constant.COIN_COST_KEY, Constant.DEFAULT_COIN_PRICE)
    val date: String = Hawk.get(Constant.COIN_DATE_KEY, Constant.DEFAULT_COIN_DATE)
    updateCoin(Coin().apply { this.cost = cost; this.date = date })

    // Handle listeners
    view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_calculate).setOnClickListener(this)
    view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btn_update).setOnClickListener(this)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need just aboutPage than change the return statement to `return aboutPage;`